# Node.JS through2 callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am new to Node.JS and trying to understand the [through2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2) library.

I wonder how the callback (in the following example code which is copied from the above link) is useful. Please explain using a small piece of code if possible.

```
fs.createReadStream('ex.txt')
  .pipe(through2(function (chunk, enc, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < chunk.length; i++)
      if (chunk[i] == 97)
        chunk[i] = 122 // swap 'a' for 'z' 

    this.push(chunk)

    callback()
   }))
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.txt'))
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe it is needed to continue the pipe chaining. If you wouldn't call it, the pipe would break.

This statement is from [through2 documentation](https://github.com/rvagg/through2#transformfunction):

> A minimal implementation should call the callback function to indicate
>   that the transformation is done, even if that transformation means
>   discarding the chunk.

Comment: Ah, a more direct documentation. Don't know how I missed it

Answer (score 3):

If you read the through2 documentation from the link you provided you'd have seen this:

> ### API
>
> through2([ options, ] [ transformFunction ] [, flushFunction ])
>
> Consult the [stream.Transform](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) documentation for the exact rules of the
>   transformFunction (i.e. this._transform) and the optional flushFunction
>   (i.e. this._flush).

Then, if you click on the `stream.Transform` link and read the documentation there, you'd get to this sooner or later: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_transform_transform_chunk_encoding_callback

And it says:

> transform._transform(chunk, encoding, callback)#
>
> - `chunk` Buffer | String The chunk to be transformed. Will always be a
>     buffer unless the decodeStrings option was set to false.
> - `encoding` String If the chunk is a string, then this is the encoding
>     type. (Ignore if decodeStrings chunk is a buffer.)
> - `callback` Function Call this function (optionally with an error 
>     argument and data) when you are done processing the supplied chunk.

So basically it's a function that you should call to signal to the stream that your're done processing. The reason you can't simply return from the function in order to signal that you're done processing is because you may have some asynchronous task (consult a database, send a packet over the network etc.) which will cause the function to return before the task is done.

Personally I think `callback` is a bad name for this. A better name would be something like Mocha's `done()` or a promise `resolve()`. Fortunately, the name of the argument is not decided by node.js or the through2 library, it's decided by you. So if I were you I'd write it like this:

```
fs.createReadStream('ex.txt')
.pipe(through2(function (chunk, enc, done) {
    for (var i = 0; i < chunk.length; i++)
      if (chunk[i] == 97)
        chunk[i] = 122; // swap 'a' for 'z' 

    this.push(chunk);

    done();
}))
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.txt'))
```

Comment: Any advice on the "chunk" Buffer, since the Buffer (from the through2 examples) is making use of properties that don't exist on the Buffer Object from the NodeJS documentation.   I've found the through2 library to be very cryptic and inconsistent.

Comment: @GuyPark What do you mean properties that don't exist on Buffer objects? The `chunk` in the README looks like a regular Buffer object to me

Comment: Seems when used in GULP, the "chunk" is a Vinyl Stream and not a buffer, which was throwing me.   I miss the good old Typed languages as they tend to have more clarity on types.

Comment: How would I wait for all chunks to be available?